# Youtube iFrame: Unsafe Javascript attempt to access frame

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I am getting this error on a website I'm working on, I have simplified the code down to the below example, which produces this error in webkit (chrome 15.0.x), I don't see the error in firefox.

I have looked around at other SO posts regarding the same error and most of them are in reference to using the youtube API and cross domain references.

I have tried:

changing the doctype, (no difference)
adding origin params to the youtube call (no difference)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body class="page front logged-in no-sidebars">
<iframe  width="393" height="230" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/QH2-TGUlwu4" frameborder="0" ></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does sounds like a cross domain security issue and those are hard (if not impossible) to overcome. Have you tried embedding the video directly onto the page without an iframe? The documentation is at http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue with cross-site messaging (where one page/website communicates with another page/website via an IFrame using javascript callbacks as a medium). It doesn't always work out and some browsers may not always catch the callback event and may register it as a security error if the protocol or port differs.